# Limit Records with SQL in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

We get an Access DB (.accdb) from an external source and have no control over the structure or data.  We need to ingest the data into our DB using code.  This means I have control over the SQL.

Our issue is that one table contains almost 13k records (currently 12,997) and takes a long time to process.  I'd like to query the data from the source DB but only a predefined number of records at a time - let's say 1000 at a time.

I tried generating my query inside a loop where I update the number the records to return with each loop.  So far, the only thing I've found that comes close to working is something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
        SELECT Top + pageSize +  sub.* 
        FROM ( 
                SELECT TOP + startPos + [Product Description Codes].* 
                FROM [Product Description Codes] 
                ORDER BY [Product Description Codes].PRODDESCRIPCODE 
        ) sub 
        ORDER BY sub.PRODDESCRIPCODE DESC 
 ) subOrdered 
ORDER BY subOrdered.PRODDESCRIPCODE
```

Where I increment *pageSize* and *startPos* with each loop.  The problem is that it ***always*** returns 1000 rows, even on what I think should be the last loop when it should return only 997 and then return zero after that.

Can anyone help me with this?  I don't have another column to filter on.  Is there a way to select a certain number of records in a loop and then increment that number until I've gotten all the records, and then stop?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by takes along time to process? 13k records is nothing and should not be slow

Comment: Right now I get all 13k records.  For each one, my code checks for an existing record in our DB.  If there's an existing record, it is updated; if there is no existing record, the current one is inserted.  I let this run yesterday, and it took 3,437,640 milliseconds to complete, which is about 57 minutes.  That's outside our performance metrics.

Comment: I saw your comment now. Wow, that is slow. Maybe you are doing the whole process wrong. Sounds like you are doing the operation one by one, where only two would do? (one for update, one for insert)

Comment: @CetinBasoz yep this is a classic N+1 selects problem

Comment: Can you add your code that checks for the record then updates/inserts based on those results?

Comment: Breaking down the input data into batches of 1000 rows is just spreading out the pain over 13 batches. It sounds like your update code is performing 13,000 table scans of the destination table. Your SO profile indicates that you work for the company that makes the software into which you are trying to import, so you should be able to find out what indexes are available in the destination table and how you might be able to take advantage of them to import the data in a more timely fashion.

Comment: It's a memory issue.  Processing all 13k records at once takes a lot more time than processing 1000 records 13 times. The data is coming back in an array (which is stored in memory) - the larger the array, the longer it takes to run.  Each insert and update command takes a minimal amount of time to run.  It's the size of the array that's slowing things down.

Answer (score 0):

If PRODDESCRIPCODE is primary key then you can simplify your select. ie:

SELECT TOP 1000 * 
FROM [Product Description Codes] 
where PRODDESCRIPCODE > @pcode;

and start with passing a @pcode parameter of 0 (if int, or '' if text etc). In next loop you would set the parameter to the max PRODDESCRIPCODE you have received.

(I am not sure if you meant MS SQL server saying SQL and how you are doing this).

Comment: PRODDESCRIPCODE is, indeed, the primary key.  When I say "SQL", I mean that I am passing a SQL string to Access using my code (which is a proprietary form or Basic).  I'll try the suggestion in a little bit and research the N+1 selects problem.

Comment: Oh you are passing SQL string. So what language is it? What is your DB? Can you do that directly from your DB (server side programming). I mean a little more detail on the subject would be much better.

Comment: It's called LIMSBasic, and it is proprietary to the application we use called LabWare LIMS.  It's very similar (but not identical) to Basic.  What more detail can I provide?  This is my first post here, so I'd like to do everything I can to help you all help me.  I appreciate everyone's interest so far.

Comment: I see. Forgive me but then I would also assume that you are not a database programmer (I may be completely wrong). I would research about the underlying database and do this with a single SQL command probably.

Comment: I am not a DB programmer, but I am familiar with basic-to-moderate SQL syntax and and can usually understand more advanced syntax and functions.  PRODDESCRIPCODE is an alphanumeric field that can be sorted.  I think all of the entries are in the form of one capital letter followed by four numeric digits.  It can be sorted

Comment: I said that, because if you were, then I would ask the details of the database you use so could give suggestions on creating the SQL needed to do this in one shot (if possible). Unfortunately commands needed to do the stuff is not the same in every type of database (and if LIMS is also using Access then I would forget writing an SQL to do this fast).

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely have to update records, or can you afford to insert the entire access table into your local table, slap on a timestamp field, and structure your local queries to grab the most recent entry?  Based on some of your comments above, it doesn't sound like you have any cases where you are keeping a local record over an imported one.

`SELECT PRODDESCRIPCODE, MAX(timestamp) FROM table GROUP BY PRODDESCRIPCODE`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a variation of the method from here:
http://www.jertix.org/en/blog/programming/implementation-of-sql-pagination-with-ms-access.html

Thank you all very much for your suggestions.